# Mac: Android Studio ADB doesn't recognise any Emulator or USB device

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.1

When I try to run a Project in Emulator or USB Device, Android Studio doesn't detect any device connected (http://prntscr.com/k99lpm). While if I run the "adb devices" command in terminal I can see connected devices.

When I use Emulator In Project Configuration ( http://prntscr.com/k99mm1 ) I got the Emulator running, Got Gradle error "0". and gives me error ( log below )

> 00:17 Gradle sync finished in 362ms (from cached state)
>
> 00:46 Error running 'app': No target device found.
>
> 00:46 Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences.
>
> 00:46 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 00:46 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 00:46 * daemon started successfully
>
> 00:46 Gradle build finished in 9s 938ms
>
> 00:47 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 00:47 Gradle build finished in 1s 45ms
>
> 00:47 Unable to open connection to: localhost/192.168.1.12:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
>
> 00:47 Connection attempts: 1
>
> 00:48 Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences.
>
> 00:48 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 00:48 * daemon started successfully
>
> 00:48 Unable to open connection to: localhost/192.168.1.12:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
>
> 00:48 Connection attempts: 2

and shows no ADB device running while emulator is on and gives error that unable to establish connection to adb Screenshot http://prntscr.com/k9bj2q

Any Help would be appreciated. thanks